# Modified 0-1 knapsack

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

There are items arranged in a row, with repetition, each kind with some cost. You have x amount with you. Also you can have liberty to set price of one kind of item to 0. But we can only select consecutive items (no skipping). What is the most no of items you can pick? Eg. abacdab, costs (a:1,b:2,c:1,d:5), x=6, so most article you can pick up is 6 (abacda, setting cost d=0).
My approach: start from abacdab, reduce one letter from right and check cost after setting cost of letter with maximum (count*cost) to 0, stop when first substring satisfies and note length as lmax.
Now repeat above step with bacda (removing first letter), but stop at substrings with length==lmax.
Is there a faster way to solve this maybe using dynamic programming?

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
cot={'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':5}
def maxarticles(s,cot,x):
    l=len(s)
    lmax=0
    smax=''
    cmax=0
    for i in range(l):
        if i+lmax==l:
            break
        for j in range(l,i+lmax,-1):
            subarr=s[i:j]
            c=cost(subarr,cot)
            print(subarr,c)
            le=j-i
            if c<=x:
                if lmax<le:
                    smax=subarr
                    lmax=le
                    cmax=c
                    print(subarr,c,lmax)
                    break
return smax,lmax,cmax

def cost(s,cot):
    counts={}
    m=0
    total=0
    for i in s:
        val=cot[i]
        if i in counts:
            counts[i]+=val
        else:
            counts[i]=val
        if counts[i]>m:
            m=counts[i]
        total+=val
    return total-m
```